# regular expression in gsub with \1 unexpected behaviour

Tags: ruby, regex, string

This example behaves as expected:

```
"cl. 23".gsub(/([0-9]+)/, '|' + '\1'.to_s + '|')
# => "cl. |23|"
```

but this doesn't:

```
"cl. 23".gsub(/([0-9]+)/, '|' + '\1'.to_i.to_s + '|')
# => "cl. |0|"
```

Why does the expression `'\1'.to_i.to_s` return `"0"`?

for more clarity, my aim is to be able to use a condition in gsub using \1:

```
 "cl. 23".gsub(/([0-9]+)/, '|' + ('\1'.to_i > 36 ? 'g' : 'service' ) + '|')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby (or in most other programming languages), all arguments are evaluated before the method call that uses them.

With the first example, the arguments are first evaluated, and becomes:

```
gsub(/([0-9]+)/, '|' + '\1'.to_s + '|')
# => gsub(/([0-9]+)/, '|' + '\1' + '|')
# => gsub(/([0-9]+)/, '|\1|')
```

On the other hand, with the second example, the arguments are evaluated and becomes:

```
gsub(/([0-9]+)/, '|' + '\1'.to_i.to_s + '|')
# => gsub(/([0-9]+)/, '|' + 0.to_s + '|')
# => gsub(/([0-9]+)/, '|' + '0' + '|')
# => gsub(/([0-9]+)/, '|0|')
```

Again, **all arguments are evaluated before the method call that uses them**. From this, it follows that, if you want the replacement string of `gsub` to depend on the match, you cannot put the replacement formula in the argument; you have to use a block. Looks like this is what you wanted:

```
"cl. 23".gsub(/([0-9]+)/){'|' + ($1.to_i > 36 ? 'g' : 'service' ) + '|'}
```

which works but actually is not smart. A better way is

```
"cl. 23".gsub(/\d+/){|s| "|#{s.to_i > 36 ? "g" : "service"}|"}
```

Answer (score 2):

`'\1'` is `"\\1"`: `\` + `1`.

It is not a valid numerical representation. (because of leading `\`); [`String#to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-to_i) returns `0` for such string.

BTW, if you want surround the number with `|`, you don't need `to_i`, `to_s`. Just use `|\1|` as replacement string.

```
"cl. 23".gsub(/([0-9]+)/, '|\1|')
# => "cl. |23|"
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are expecting the method `to_i` to be called on the group matched by the regexp. Actually it is called on the string `'\1'`.

`String#to_i` returns `0` because, as the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-to_i) says:

> If there is not a valid number at the start of str, 0 is returned.

```
irb> '\1'.to_i
# => 0
```